# Can Xamarin's Monotouch.dll be referenced directly?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I've started working on a Xamarin solution (a brown-field project) in Visual Studio 2013.

One of the projects is missing a reference to monotouch.dll.

I see that the DLL can be found in the following path on my machine, but don't know if I should be referencing it directly:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoTouch\v1.0

I checked the GAC for the assembly and NuGet as well, but couldn't find it there.

**Is it OK to reference monotouch.dll from the above folder path? Or should it be referenced another way?**

Note that I have Xamarin 3.8 installed, with Xamarin.iOS 8.4. Also note that we don't want to switch to the Unified API just yet, hence the reliance on monotouch.dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you create a new Classic API project you will see that monotouch.dll is referenced from that path.

Answer (score 0):

@Rdavisau's answer is correct, but I also disovered what went wrong. I opened the old VS2010 project in VS2013, and I think VS2013 changed my target framework references on my projects.

I fixed this by editing the CSProj file and deleting the default CSharp targets:

And only keeping the Xamarin targets:

When doing this, the Monotouch.dll is automatically referenced in the right place.